# A Closed subset of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces

I can guess that set of Nilpotent Matrices are closed in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, But I am not able to make it rigorous; I have thought the map $A\mapsto A^k$ is continuous. But then? Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $A$ is nilpotent, then $A^n=0$. Since the map $f(A):=A^n$ is continuous, $\operatorname{Nil}(M_n(\mathbb R)):=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb R): \exists p\in\mathbb N_{>0}, A^p=0\}=f^{-1}(\{0_{M_n}\})$ is closed.

Comment: Caro Davide, $\operatorname{Nil}(M_n(\mathbb R))=F_n$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg In fact, yes, I realize that the $F_p$ are nested. And we have less characters to type. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Davide: and +1  for your answer, by the way!

Answer (score 1):

Since the map $m_k: A\rightarrow A^k$ is continuous and  $A$ is nilpotent of order $\leq k$

iff 
$A\in m_k^{-1}(0)$ is closed (because $\{0\}$ is closed)

we have $\operatorname{Nil}(M_n(\mathbb R))=\bigcup_{k=1}^n m_k^{-1}(0)$ also is closed.

Comment: Dear Matrix, you should definitely not write  $Ker(m_k)$, because  $m_k$ is not a linear mapping.

Comment: @ Georges Yes !!, thnx for the remark.